# How to resume moving an image the way it was moving before?

Tags: jquery, html

```
var leftright = 0;
//left is 0
//right is 1

$(document).ready(function(){
$("#StartContinue").click(function(){
    if (leftright === 0)
    {
        function imgLeft() {
            $("#b").animate({left: "-=1000"}, 5000, "swing", imgRight);
        }
        leftright = 0;
    }
    else
    {
        function imgRight() {
            $("#b").animate({left: "+=1000"}, 5000, "swing", imgLeft);
        }
        leftright = 1;
    }

    imgRight();
});

    $("#Stop").click(function(){
        $("#b").stop(true, false);
    });
});
```

What it does is move right and left across the screen. When I press my stop button when the image is going back to the left and I continue the movement with the other button, it continues going right instead of left like it was moving before I pressed stop. I want it to resume the way it was moving before I pressed stop, instead of always going right.

Also, it seems to start the cycle again. Meaning it will go another 1000 pixels when it's already traveled 500. How do I make it so it travels a max. distance?

HTML:

```
<head>
<title>Assignment3</title>
<script src = "jquery-1.11.1.js"></script>
<script type = "text/javascript"  src = "jquery3-functions.js"></script>
</head>

<body>
   <button id="StartContinue">Start/Continue</button>
   <button id="Stop">Stop</button>
   <br />
   <div id="b" style="background:#98bf21;height:100px;width:100px;position:absolute;">
</body>

</html>
```

Comment: Can you post your HTML as well?

Comment: There you go. Html is there.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Don't place functions inside an if/else block. Also, don't place your CSS inline.

Try the following code: (click [here](http://jsfiddle.net/Lam3kx04/) for a working example)

```
$(document).ready(function(){

    var curPosition = 0;
    var curDirection = 'right';
    var maxDistance = 500;

    $("#StartContinue").click(function(){
        move();
    });

    $("#Stop").click(function(){
        stop();
    });

    function move()
    {
        if(curDirection == 'right' )
        {
            moveRight();
        }
        else
        {
            moveLeft();
        }
    }

    function moveRight()
    {
        curPosition = $("#b").position().left;
        curDirection ="right";
        var travel = maxDistance - curPosition;
        $("#b").animate({left: "+="+travel}, 1000, "swing", moveLeft);
    }

    function moveLeft()
    {
        curPosition = $("#b").position().left;
        curDirection ="left";
        var travel = curPosition;
        $("#b").animate({left: "-="+travel}, 1000, "swing", moveRight);
    }

    function stop() {
        $("#b").stop(true, false);
    }
});
```

Comment: Thanks very much Yoav. Works perfectly, exactly what I wanted. I thought I hadn't explained my issue properly in my post haha.